# Can I binding another Executing Window on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, binding

I'm designing new program that combining much exe CLI programs into one GUI program.

First, I will use ProcessStartInfo class for executing exe programs inside of GUI Program.
Then, Each result from exe programs will be displayed on GUI program.

But, I have problem with some of exe programs.

Because of There's have another windows except basic CLI window.
One of CLI exe programs, It has OpenCV window used with cvNamedWindow on Code.
When using it, There's two windows - CLI, OpenCV Window.

I want to combine this OpenCV Window to One GUI, also.

I think, It needs to binding another executing windows on WPF Controls.
Is there any idea for Combining each windows of CLI exe programs?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I think putting the window of another process within the wpf window would usually be called host rather than bind. Like https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/673701/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WPF-Window-Applicati

Comment: @Andy Thanks for comment for me! It sounds good for me. I will try it. Thanks! :)